# Cloud9 nodejs web application asking for login

Tags: cloud9-ide

I have a 'hello world' nodejs application in C9. It works if I am logged in to C9. But it doesn't if I am not. I get a C9 login page instead if not. Is there any means to open the application to public? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the app public by going to the sharing settings in the top right corner of the IDE and make the app public.